# Would putting a dead animal in the freezer contaminate other food?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

If you put a dead animal in the freezer, wrapped in a plastic bag, lay the dead animal on top of the other food in the freezer, can the smell of the dead animal contaminate the other food in the freezer just from the odor?

Comment: Smells will travel from item to item in the freezer, yes.

Comment: I just want to know why you are asking this. Strange question.

Comment: @CindyAskew Unfortunately, it seems plausible it's a dead pet :(

Comment: If it is a dead pet, I am so very sorry for your loss. Unfortunately I was in the same situation a few years ago. No leeway on smell or contamination. Please have your pet buried or cremated as soon as you can. I'm sure that I speak for many others in the community, as well as for myself, when I express my sincere condolences. Much comfort wished. It's never easy. ...to God's ears.

Comment: People who work with dead animals, like taxidemists (sp?) often freeze roadkill to work on later, housemates are often not happy.

Comment: Are we talking with or without the offal? I'm unsure what you mean by dead animal, all meat is dead animals or at least a part of it.

Answer (score 7):

Anything you store in the freezer needs to be airtight, or odors will propagate. And they'll linger in the freezer itself, not just the other food, so you really want to avoid this.

If you're using plastic bags to store things in your freezer (and they're not zip-seal bags), make sure they're thick and tied off airtight. No harm using multiple bags to make extra sure!

Answer (score 3):

I read this question differently, and it may not be the original poster's intent, but I wonder if @mandi porter was asking if bacterial contamination can be transported by odor.  Of course, the smell is an indication of bacterial spoilage, but it is not where the bacteria reside.